# ShellExecute can not pass parameter to chrome.exe

Tags: c++, visual-c++, window

I can pass parameter `--user-data-dir=“”`  in my laptop，but fail in myfriend‘s.

I want to set different `--user-data-dir` to login a website with multi-user at
the same time.

```
CString param=agent+_T("-in-process-plugins --url m.xiaomi.com/home/index.html ")+datadir;
SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo = {0};
ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpVerb = _T("open");
ShExecInfo.lpFile = exename;
ShExecInfo.lpParameters = param;
ShExecInfo.lpDirectory =filedir;
ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;
ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `C#`? Why aren't you using `"` in `--user-data-dir=“”`?

Comment: isorry parameter datadir="--user-data-dir="xxxxx"